# DELETE from mysql table WHERE column equals value AND column2 equals value2

Tags: php, mysql

Having some trouble getting this query to work correctly.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '$id' AND 'username' = '$username' ");
```

tried replacing variables with actual data and running it in phpmyadmin to no success

any thoughts?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're quoting the username column with ' instead of `

use:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '$id' AND `username` = '$username'");
```

not:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '$id' AND 'username' = '$username'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, for the love of the internet, don't built an SQL query yourself. Use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).